# Azure IOT Suite how to create a dashboard to display sensor data

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, dashboard, azure-iot-hub

I am new to Azure. I have sensors and would like to send data from sensors to the Azure backend, preferably to a database. After collecting those sensor data I would like to display them on a dashboard. I wonder if there is a sample tutorial or source code to implement such a solution. Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is far too broad to get anything other than opinions and suggestions which isn't a good fit for Stackoverflow's Q&A style. As a result it is likely to be closed. If you can make your question about a specific issue you are having then you're more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: There is a dashboard included in both the IOT demo solutions

Answer (score 1):

The Azure IoT Suite is an accelerator that configures a solution using standard Azure services and each one comes with a dashboard.  The source code is available on GitHub: [Remote Monitoring](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring) and [Predictive Maintenance](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-predictive-maintenance)

Comment: Can I run those samples on local PC?

Comment: And those samples include SQL Database solution? Because I would like to store sensor data into SQL database then display data on a dashboard.

Comment: Should I use Power BI for dashboard?

Comment: any sample using SQL Server and Power BI?

Comment: I would be glad if you can provide me SQL DB + Power BI sample.

Comment: or instead of SQL DB should I use Stream Analytics Job? But how can I store data for later usage?

Comment: Yes you can use Stream Analytics to query the IoT Hub.  You can have multiples outputs, let's say one saving to a database and a second one to send some data to Power Bi.  Take a look at this series of blog posts I wrote documenting an IoT demo I did using Event Hub: http://blog.guybarrette.com/post/2015/08/12/Building-an-IoT-and-Azure-demo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of achieving this as Azure is not a final product but consists of different "modules" if you will.

If the idea is to create a dashboard that shows the sensor data, you don't necessarily need to store them into a database. You can create live streams and display them. If the storage of data is also of concern, then in parallel you can do that as well.

The redirection logic of the data here would be Stream Analytics, it works with the concepts of an input sink, a query and an output sink. Now in your case you might want to create an Event Hub/ IoT Hub, then use it as an input sink to the Stream Analytics, and use PowerBI as the output sink. This will get the data and display it in PBi. If you also want to store the data, you can add another output sink for different options like , blob storage, document db, azure sql database etc.

Also there is an  Azure IoT suite remote monitoring solution, that automates most of those tasks with some extra modules, you can use that to create a solution and use it as a boilerplate.

Below are step-by-step tutorials for;

Event Hubs

Stream analytics

PowerBI

Hope this helps!

Mert